# pandas, How to add rows with average grouped columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below.
I want to add 1 row for each fruit, where

- the `price` for the new row should be set to the average price of the pre-existing rows for that fruit.
- the `resource` for the new row will always be `all`.
- the `ftype` for the new rows will always be `avg`.

I know how to generate a new column showing the average price for each fruit, but I don't know how to add a row with this average.
Can you help me?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
fruit = ['apple','apple','banana','banana','kiwi','kiwi','grape','grape']
ftype = ['one','two','one','two','three','one','one','two']
resource = ['us','us','us','us','us','us','us','us']
price = [100,150,200,300,120,300,400,500]
df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit':fruit,'ftype':ftype,'resource':resource,'price':price})
print(df)
```

Original dataframe:

```
    fruit  ftype  price resource
0   apple    one    100       us
1   apple    two    150       us
2  banana    one    200       us
3  banana    two    300       us
4    kiwi  three    120       us
5    kiwi    one    300       us
6   grape    one    400       us
7   grape    two    500       us
```

What I want to generate:

```
    fruit  ftype  price resource
0   apple    one    100       us
1   apple    two    150       us
    apple    avg    125      all
2  banana    one    200       us
3  banana    two    300       us
   banana    avg    250       all
4    kiwi  three    120       us
5    kiwi    one    300       us
     kiwi    avg    210       all
6   grape    one    400       us
7   grape    two    500       us
    grape    avg    450       all
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can aggregate `mean` and add new columns with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('fruit', as_index=False)['price'].mean().assign(resource='all',ftype='avg')
```

Then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and sorting values:

```
df = (pd.concat([df, df1], sort=True)
        .sort_values(['fruit','resource'], ascending=[True, False])
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
     fruit  ftype  price resource
0    apple    one    100       us
1    apple    two    150       us
2    apple    avg    125      all
3   banana    one    200       us
4   banana    two    300       us
5   banana    avg    250      all
6    grape    one    400       us
7    grape    two    500       us
8    grape    avg    450      all
9     kiwi  three    120       us
10    kiwi    one    300       us
11    kiwi    avg    210      all
```

Comment: wow.. thank you for fast answering.. I tried and It's working perfectly thanks:)

Comment: @dideod98, remember to "accept" this as your answer by clicking the checkmark, and upvote any answers you find helpful, if you have not already :-)